# How to list "compile" configuration's "provided" dependencies? I would like to download all of the dependencies

Tags: gradle

To list `dependencies` with `gradle`:

```
gradlew dependencies
```

This will show the all of the dependencies in your current projects `configurations`.

For example:

```
testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
+--- org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.1.2
|    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.1.2
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-resources:3.1.2
|    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.1.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.0.1
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1
|    |    |    |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.1.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:2.1
|    |    |    |         +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    |    |    |         +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    |    |         |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    |    |    |         \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1
|    |    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.1.2
|    |    |    +--- com.ximpleware:vtd-xml:2.11
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
|    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.1.2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:5.0.1
|    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.1
|    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46
|    |    +--- com.ximpleware:vtd-xml:2.11
|    |    +--- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.8
|    |    |    +--- xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1
|    |    |    \--- xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c
|    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.0
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.0
|    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- classworlds:classworlds:1.1-alpha-2
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
|    |    |    |    +--- junit:junit:3.8.1 -> 4.12 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.0.4 -> 1.5.15
|    |    |    |    \--- classworlds:classworlds:1.1-alpha-2
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.4.2 -> 1.5.15
|    |    |    |    \--- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-project:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-model:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.11
|    |    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:1.5.15
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:2.2.1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:2.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:1.0-beta-6
|    |    |    |    |    +--- nekohtml:xercesMinimal:1.9.6.2
|    |    |    |    |    +--- nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.6.2
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-6 (*)
|    |    \--- org.robolectric:shadows-core-v23:3.1.2
|    |         +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.1.2
|    |         +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-resources:3.1.2 (*)
|    |         +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.1.2 (*)
|    |         +--- com.almworks.sqlite4java:sqlite4java:0.282
|    |         \--- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:53.1
|    \--- org.robolectric:shadows-core-v23:3.1.2 (*)
```

Notice, the `shadows-support-v4` artifact brings in `robolectric` artifact which brings in the dependency: `org.robolectric:shadows-core-v23:3.1.2`.

If we go to the `build.gradle` file, we notice there are `provided` dependencies that are not brought in: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/f68ba6bcb51fb25a28805a3c5f7ffcee2d9560d5/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/build.gradle#L16.

Actual pom file: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robolectric/robolectric/3.1.2/robolectric-3.1.2.pom. Provided dependencies are not added to the POM but the `runtime` dependencies are.

How can I go deeper and list all of the dependencies of the dependencies including any `provided` dependencies?

Comment: Are you interested in showing the provided dependencies in the output of `gradle dependencies` task, or are you interested in adding them to the published POM?

Comment: Also note that though gradle supports configuration `compileOnly` since version 2.12, the roboelectric code you linked to is using [their own implementation of "provided" configuration](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/provided.groovy), which doesn't seem to extend the maven publish part to correctly add provided dependencies to the published POM

Comment: @RaGe I actually just needed to download the dependencies. I didn't like that robolectric's transitive "provided" dependencies were downloaded while running the tests on upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2646

**For those that are still having this problem, download all the dependencies and transitive dependencies up front for your CI:**

```
subprojects { project ->
    task downloadDependencies(type: Copy) {
        description "Downloads all dependencies."
        group "build"

        from {
            // Use of closure defers evaluation until execution time
            project.configurations
                .findAll { configuration -> configuration.canBeResolved }
                .collect { configuration -> configuration.resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration.files }
        }
        into "$project.buildDir/dependencies"
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
Step 1: gradlew downloadDependencies
Step 2: gradlew assembleDebug testDebug
```